# Finding value in two ranges

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have data ranges in two columns shown below. I use "vlookup" formula in order to get value of columns B. However I need to find the value between ranges like "60" in column A. Naturally, result is 4,73%, if I use "true" option in "vlookup". But I want to get exact value between 4,73% and 4,64%. Please provide your valuable answers. Thanks.

```
A    B
50  4,73%
100 4,64%
150 4,55%
200 4,46%
250 4,37%
300 4,28%
350 4,19%
400 4,10%
450 4,01%
500 3,92%
550 3,83%
```

Answer (score 2):

```
= FORECAST(60, B2:B12, A2:A12)
```